# JPA Repository method doesn't work

Tags: spring-boot, junit, jhipster

SportsRepository.java file is like below.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@Repository
public interface SportsRepository extends JpaRepository<Sport, Long> {
  public static final String GET_Players = "SELECT players FROM sport_tbl";

  @Query(value = GET_Players, nativeQuery = true)
  List<String> getPlayers();
}
```

SportFestResourceIntTest.java shows below.

```
@Test
@Transactional
public void testGetPlayers() {
    List<String> actual = SportsRepository.getPlayers();
    List<String> expected = Arrays.asList("Admin", "Committee Member", "Lecturer");
    assertThat(actual).isEqualTo(expected);      
}
```

When I type gradle test in command prompt it will throw an exception(org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException saying db is already closed.) In the log actual is empty.(<>). I changed the url in application-dev.yml by adding DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE. But not resolved. So I have no idea where I went wrong. I implemented only this code to accomplish the task. Can anyone help please?

Comment: `SportsRepository` or `sportsRepository`  in the test class ?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. But still exception is in

Comment: upvoted 3 times? Maybe I miss something. But you should autowire your repository and use spring context or mock it.

Comment: Yh. That was already autowired by jhipster

Comment: do you have the spring context while your test is running?

Comment: How to implement it? Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: Can you tell us what exception is raised ? Maybe your database is empty

Comment: No has data in the db. exception is saying  actual is empty.(<>) .

Comment: Before autowired do I need to map?

Comment: No what I need is what is the exception type ? Not the message ?

Comment: sorry that was org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException. Saying db is already closed. I updated the post @Dimitri

Comment: what should I do now? I already attempted to correct that error.

Comment: Ok remove the `@Transactional` in the test method ?

Comment: Still same error was there even by removing @Transactional

Comment: What happens if you add `List<Sport> findAll()` to your interface?  Does the method return data from your DB? If so, do you really require a native query?

Comment: Actually I need a method to get all the records of one column in the table. Then I need to test that method. So I have no solution yet for that. @Robert H

Comment: @A.Wen I would try what I had mentioned above - if that works its easy enough to iterate over the list and extract the one field you need...

Comment: That method returns a entity type object I guess. How to convert it to String?

Comment: Call the property in the Sports class - something like sport.getPlayer() I would imagin

Comment: You can use streams/lambda to map entities to a list

Comment: Something like `List<String> players = sports.stream().map(Sport::getPlayer).collect(Collectors.toList());`